# Definition of Immersion of Schemes in Liu Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In exercise 3.2.3 of Qing Liu's book Algebraic Geometry he defines an immersion of schemes to be "a morphism which is an open immersion followed by a closed immersion."

However, on the Stacks Project Section 26.10 'Immersion of Schemes' they define a morphism of schemes to be an immersion "if it can be factored as $j\circ i$ where $i$ is a closed immersion and $j$ is an open immersion."

In the exercise in Liu's book it is shown that the two notions are very similar. Indeed, if $f=i\circ j$ where $j$ is an open and $i$ is a closed immersion, $f$ can be decomposed as a closed immersion followed by an open immersion. And, if $f=j\circ i$ where $i$ is an closed immersion and $j$ is a quasi-compact open immersion, $f$ can be written as an open followed by a closed immersion.

Which of the definitions is 'standard'?

Thanks!

Comment: If you consider on Noetherian schemes, the two coincide. See [29.3 Immersions](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RJ). There are also lemmas and examples explaining this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Liu's errata to the book from his website, he has decided to change the definition to agree with the one in EGA and stack exchange. One reason he provides is that this definition is stable under composition.
See his website: [https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~qliu/Book/](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Eqliu/Book/)
This answers the question for me.